# How to import certificate in Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows-10, ssl, certificate

When trying to import a certificate into the Personal certificate store on a Windows 10 box, I get an error: "The import failed because the store was read-only, the store was full, or the store did not open correctly." Background on this problem points to specifying the physical store as Local Computer and importing the certificate into that location. When expanding the Personal folder to show the physical stores there is only the Registry store, not Local Computer.

[cert store with physical stores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbb4W.png)

Is it not possible to import to Local Computer or is Registry just another name for this?

Comment: Why are you not using the certificate manager

Comment: I'm using certlm.msc, certificate manager for local machine.

Comment: hi, see if it's helpful to you: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=792232

Comment: Thank you, I did see something like that for allowing import into trusted root, but I am importing into the Personal store.  Do I still need that group policy?

Comment: Are you sure you understand the difference between certlm.msc and certmgr.msc? One is for the machine, the other for the user.

Comment: Correct, I want certlm to allow ssl for a service running as another user.  Does that make sense to do?